# What is the best way to approximate class.getSimpleName() without loading class?

Tags: java, reflection

Given a fully qualified class name that *can* be loaded with Class.forName(), is there a way to transform the name into what would be the result of loading the class and invoking getSimpleName() without actually attempting to load the class?
I need this capability for reflection purposes.

Comment: I guess you would have to implement the logic yourself - it's mainly getting the last item in a `.` separated `String`; with some bells and whistles...

Comment: @BoristheSpider and the string might also contain a `$`

Comment: @wero yup, "bells and whistles" - if it's `\$\d+$` then `null`, otherwise split on `$`.

Comment: Let's not forget array types...

Comment: Depending on how much information you have about the class, you can just duplicate the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getSimpleName%28%29).

Comment: @shmosel As long as you don't mind getting infected by the GPL...

Comment: @shmosel unfortunately the code relies on `getSimpleBinaryName` which uses `getEnclosingClass()` therefore requires the class to be loaded

Comment: I wasn't suggested copy/paste. I was suggesting duplicating the *logic*.

Comment: @shmosel sure. But given only the qualified name you cannot know if a `$` is part of the simple name - see answer of @AndyTurner. The `getSimpleBinaryName()` allows you to decide that.

Comment: @wero, valid point. But I think we've all overlooked the fact that OP wants to **approximate** the class name. Maybe these corner cases don't even matter?

Comment: @shmosel depends on how useful it is to be not exactly correct. I can't think what you could possibly do (other than printing something to console) without the actual name.

Comment: @AndyTurner, and what would you do with the actual name?

Comment: Well, stuff. You could generate code referring to the class, for example. Or just print "You have a class named Blah with a method called bloo()", which you can then go and find in the code. I don't know what OP is really trying to do.

Comment: @AndyTurner, it's not for code generation, because they use different syntax for inner classes (`.` vs. `$`). And printing something for reference is just the type of scenario where accuracy is not critical.

Comment: @shmosel right - and you need to know the simple name of the class and its containing classes to be able to generate that syntax correctly. And "where accuracy is not critical" - I was trying to make the point that printing a message accurately is not critical in the causing-a-runtime-failure sense, but it can send you on a wild goose chase and waste your time looking for a class that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say that you can't do it simply based on the name.

You can try to split on `.` and `$`, but this example code demonstrates that it is not always obvious where the simple name begins:

```
class Ideone
{
    private static class Bar {};

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      class Foo$o {
        class Bar$bar {}
      };
      class Foo$o$Bar {
        class Bar$bar {}
      };
      class Foo$o$Bar$Bar$bar {}
      print(Ideone.class);
      print(Bar.class);
      print(Foo$o.class);
      print(Foo$o.Bar$bar.class);
      print(Foo$o$Bar.Bar$bar.class);
      print(Foo$o$Bar$Bar$bar.class);
    }

    private static void print(Class<?> clazz) {
        System.out.printf("fqn=%s, sn=%s%n", clazz.getName(), clazz.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fqn=Ideone, sn=Ideone
fqn=Ideone$Bar, sn=Bar
fqn=Ideone$1Foo$o, sn=Foo$o
fqn=Ideone$1Foo$o$Bar$bar, sn=Bar$bar
fqn=Ideone$1Foo$o$Bar$Bar$bar, sn=Bar$bar
fqn=Ideone$2Foo$o$Bar$Bar$bar, sn=Foo$o$Bar$Bar$bar
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/O5P7Yj)

i.e. if you were to say "the bit of the name after the final `$` or `.`", you'd be wrong.

The only conclusive way to do this is to load the class, potentially without initializing it:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className, false, someClassLoadeR);
```

Comment: Or come up with a comprehensive set of cases  - as you have demonstrated there are not that many - and implement it. Unit testing would be nicely trivial.

Comment: @BoristheSpider but you could have a nested class called `Fo` with a nested class called `o` instead.

Comment: Oh, actually, I see - there is a `1` present in the local class name.

Comment: @BoristheSpider but I think I have cooked up a more vile case now where it's not possible to tell where to split the name...

Comment: I think you may be right - there are simpler cases, such as top level classes have `$` in the name. Also the fact that the API code required the `class` to be loaded might hint at the impossibility of the task.

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated by the answer of @AndyTurner you cannot derive the simple name from the qualified class string in all cases.

But if the constraint *without actually attempting to load the class* does not forbid to read the contents of the class file, you could do the following (for the edge cases):

1. Get a `InputStream` for the class file contents via `Class.getResourceAsStream()`
2. Parse the beginning of the class file and read the super class name from the constant pool.
3. (as commented by @shmosel) Implement the logic of `Class.getSimpleName()`. The super class name allows you to replace `Class.getSimpleBinaryString()` which relies on an already loaded class.

Comment: This feels jolly hard instead of just loading the class.

Comment: @AndyTurner the OP will know if it is worth the effort.